# Rolling back previous triggers when an error occurs in a later trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, dml

I am trying to understand SQL Server's triggers. As an example, we have a scenario with a table that has multiple triggers for `insert`.

**If we have an issue in the last trigger, throw an error, and call to rollback the transaction, do the previous triggers *also* rollback?**

In this scenario, we are talking about DML triggers and they are sequential, not nested. We are also referring to two or three insert or update triggers. We are using trigger order, so we know which trigger in the series is the "last" trigger to execute.

Comment: Well - **all** triggers are executed **in the context** of the transaction that caused them to be fired - that `INSERT` statement that caused them to fire. So any trigger rolling back will roll back **the entire transaction** - the `INSERT` statement, and any previous trigger operations

Comment: I suggest you take note of the maintenance issue that triggers are causing and consider a solution that doesn't use any triggers if possible

Comment: Thanks Marc, you are saying that yes, the entire insert (for example) will be rolled back so the triggers and the actual insert will fail because the complete series of triggers will not commit.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, not an option.  The vendor has added 1 or 2 triggers and if we add our own I need to understand what happens if one errors and calls to rollback.  In our testing, we've seen what marc_s has pointed out but I want to be certain of the transaction process.

Comment: I'm saying: the original operation (your `INSERT`) and **any trigger(s)** will be executed within a **single transaction** - and if you roll back a transaction, **any and all** changes it has made are reverted back

Comment: Basically you might want to reconsider the "if we add our own" bit - there might be other non trigger solutions to do what you want to do.

Comment: In order to actually assist we need to know what your trigger does, and what your ideal result is if an error occurs within your trigger. In some cases errors can be caught and/or ignored or other actions taken. So it really depends what behaviour you re looking for.

Comment: And is your unspoken requirement that if your trigger breaks nothing else is affected? Please [edit] your question to clarify the situation.

Comment: @DaleK, thx, sure, let me be more specific.  The DB is owned by a vendor and their triggers watch for any change (or delete) to a row to make sure that if it is not violating constraints (they don't have many relationships and FKs).      We are adding our trigger to the same table but all we want to do is audit the change by adding a row into a separate table.  So we are just auditing the changes while they are enforcing constaints/business logic.  If their trigger fails, I don't want our trigger to write a row in the audit table.  I think we are safe but just want to ask the pros for help.

Comment: @DaleK, the requirement or expectation is if a change occurs and if that table has 2 or 3 triggers and one trigger fails then all triggers and the data change for the table all row back.   I want it to be all or nothing. A DML trigger acts after the row save, so trigger 1 is completed successfully, and same fore trigger 2 BUT trigger 3 checks some logic and throws an error.  My hope is that trigger 1 and 2 are negated and the same with the row action on that table.  I think the answer is yes, all are thrown away on error but I just want to make sure...

Comment: marc_s has answered you in that case.

Comment: @marc_s Technically speaking (being pedantic), it's not the same *execution context*, but it is the same *transaction*. Eg local variables do not pass over, and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` and `ANSI_NULLS` don't pass across either. Any settings changes, such as `NOCOUNT`, get rolled back at the end of the trigger